# How should I eliminate gaps in wood-grain miter joints?

Tags: stairs, vinyl-flooring, miter

I just installed some Cap-A-Tread vinyl stair treads. Basically, these are 5/8" thick MDF boards that wrap around existing treads and give them a new "look" because of a thin vinyl layer. The vinyl is a wood pattern that matches my floors.

The steps have an exposed side, and the Cap-A-Tread have mitered "returns" to deal with this. However, the miters aren't great, and there are decent-sized gaps on the outside corners. With crown molding, this isn't a problem as it's usually all white so a combination of caulk and paint could effectively hide any gaps. With dark wood grain, I don't really have this option.

What's the best way to hide the gap of a mediocre miter on wood-look vinyl?

Comment: Could you post a picture of what you're talking about?

Comment: Color match caulk is available from laminate manufacturer like Wilson art  Formica  in big box stores near the countertops and sheet laminate. Pick one close to your tread color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use the same stuff you use to [fill gaps in other laminate products](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Roberts-3-oz-Brown-Wood-Laminate-and-Vinyl-Putty-PC7725/204846101?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal2_rr-_-100078126-_-204846101-_-N).  I don't know how well it will hold up on the edge of a stair (in terms of working its way out of the gaps over time), but it'll at least blend in with the floor.  That stuff is made by a few companies in many colors to match a variety of laminates.  Should be available at your local big box hardware store.

For anyone in the dark about the Cap-A-Tread product, it's a laminate product designed to go over existing stair treads.  Kind of like the granite countertop systems that just lay on top of existing laminate countertops.  Looks like this:

[image]

It can also be ordered with a mitered edge piece that covers up the exposed stair end in the case of an open stair end, as OP is describing.  Basically a one-piece alternative to plank-and-bullnose for laminate on stairs.

Comment: This is the exact sort of thing I hoped to find, thanks!